# Change to rc.local causing hang on tty1

Tags: console, init-script, signals

I added a script execution command to my `rc.local` but forgot to run it in a separate tty. The script has an infinite loop and has hung my tty1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> does not do anything and I don't have another bash login that would allow me to kill the script.

Is there a keyboard command that will start a bash login?
Is there any other way to kill the script?

Comment: @wurtel - add your ssh comment as an answer as I have deleted my answer because rc.local is the last thing run **before** `/sbin/mingetty` sets up the ttys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `rc.local` is the last script that is run before the tty's are respawned by `/bin/mingetty`, therefore, the tty terminals will not be available to log into.

However, networking and `sshd` will be running so just `ssh` to the host and kill the process as the `root` user.

Comment: unfortunately none of these have shells running. I think they normally do but perhaps my rc.local change has interrupted that ?

Comment: Try logging in via the network, the `ssh` daemon is probably already running. Then you can `su` to root and kill the script.

Comment: Edited my answer to avoid unneccessary views / answers to an answered question. @wurtel, I will make it up to you ;o).